# Number of ring endomorphisms

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Consider the ring $S=\begin{Bmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\0&a\end{pmatrix}: a,b\in \mathbb Z\end{Bmatrix}$. I am trying to find total number of endomorphisms of $S$. Since The only endomorphisms on $\mathbb Z$ zero and identity functions, therefore, they can be extended to get the zero and identity endomorphisms on $S$. Another endomorphism on $S$ will be $f(\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\0&a\end{pmatrix})=\begin{pmatrix}a&-b\\0&a\end{pmatrix}$. Is there any other endomorphism? Please help!

Comment: $f(\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\0&a\end{pmatrix})=\begin{pmatrix}a&0\\0&a\end{pmatrix}$ and $f(\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\0&a\end{pmatrix})=\begin{pmatrix}b&a\\0&b\end{pmatrix}$ seem to be endomorphisms. Also, use the fact that composition of endomorphisms is an endomorphism.

Comment: Dear @lisyarus The second map you propose is 1-1, but it does not preserve the identity of the ring (in fact, it maps the identity to a nilpotent element.) I think the user is talking about ring homomorphisms, so I don't think this map works. The first map is fine, of course. Regards

Comment: @rschwieb sure, didn't notice that it doesn't preserve identity, only checked that it preserves multiplication. Thank you!

Comment: @lisyarus An error must have slipped by when checking multiplication too, because $f(\left[\begin{smallmatrix}1&0\\0&1\end{smallmatrix}\right]^2)\neq 0$ but $f(\left[\begin{smallmatrix}1&0\\0&1\end{smallmatrix}\right])^2= 0$. Anyhow, no big deal :)

Comment: @rschwieb seems like. My bad, thank you again :)

Answer (score 2):

Let $f$ be an endomorphism of $S$. If $f(I)=0$ we get  the zero map, otherwise we must have $f(I)=I$. In this case, since
$$\left(\begin{matrix} a&b\\0&a\end{matrix}\right)=aI+b\left(\begin{matrix} 0&1\\0&0\end{matrix}\right)$$ 
we get
$$f\left(\begin{matrix} a&b\\0&a\end{matrix}\right)=aI+bf\left(\begin{matrix} 0&1\\0&0\end{matrix}\right)$$ 
Now, since $$\left(\begin{matrix} 0&1\\0&0\end{matrix}\right)^2=\left(\begin{matrix} 0&0\\0&0\end{matrix}\right)$$ then
$$\left[f\left(\begin{matrix} 0&1\\0&0\end{matrix}\right)\right]^2=\left(\begin{matrix} 0&1\\0&0\end{matrix}\right)$$
The only elements of $S$ that satisiefs $x^2=0$ are of the form
$$\left(\begin{matrix} 0&k\\0&0\end{matrix}\right)$$
with $k\in\mathbb{Z}$.
Hence $f$ must be of the form
$$f\left(\begin{matrix} a&b\\0&a\end{matrix}\right)=aI+b\left(\begin{matrix} 0&kb\\0&0\end{matrix}\right)=\left(\begin{matrix} a&kb\\0&a\end{matrix}\right)$$
and you can verify that for every $k$ you actually obtain an endomorphsim of $S$.